# Using dynamic instance variable in partial Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stumped. I want to use an instance variable in my navbar to show dynamic content from a table.

In terms of file structure, within my Views, I have a /layouts folder. Within that folder, there is a **_header.html.erb** for the navbar that is placed in the view through `<%= render 'layouts/header' %>` in **application.html.erb** file.

Now here's where it gets sticky. In my navbar, I have a set of links. I want it to render an instance variable as a link (the text it shows, not the path), so I am writing:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li> 
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
           <li><%= link_to "My Example", myexample_path %></li> 
           <li><%= link_to @example, stack_path %></li>
  </ul>
```

I have tried doing two different things with the instance variable.

So I need to define `@example = Stack.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:points)` to return a number that I want to place in that navbar. I have tried putting that instance in the Application Controller *and* by making a Layouts Controller and placing it there in `def index`.

Therefore, my question is: to create an instance variable to be read by this **_layouts.html.erb** file, which controller is appropriate to use?

As a final note, whether I add it to the Application Controller or Layouts Controller, it simply doesn't render. If I remove the `@example` instance and instead put static text, it will add it to the navbar. So this seems to be my issue.

Comment: <%= render 'header' %> try this or put header.htm.erb in shared directory and use this <%= render 'shared/header' %>

Comment: @uzaif - Just to be clear, the layouts/_header.html.erb is actually rendering, all except the dynamic content. I am confused as to which controller needs to be used to connect it to the header file if I want to store an instance variable. Does your solution address that?

Comment: write method in application controller and access it with before filter return the variable which you need in header.html.erb

Comment: That works. Thank you!

Comment: can i post as answer ?

Answer (score 2):

> in application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :add_header_text

  def add_header_text
   @menu = Menu.all 
  end

end
```

Now @menu instance variable is available in header partial